# InputProcessor of libgdx does not fire

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to get a simple libgdx project running on Android. Everything is fine, but my InputProcessor does not fire its events. 
I implemented everything according to this tutorial:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup#Code_Example

The first call of "showToast" works fine and is shown on my screen => The showToast-Method does work. Unfortunately, I can't fire any of the InputProcessor events. Even the debugger does not stop there, so they are definitely not called.

Edit: Here is the complete code. I only omitted the Calculator Class, since it works fine and should not be of any conern here. If anyone disagrees with that I can always add it, of course.

**Surface Class in libgdx main project (Main class so to say)**

```
public class Surface implements ApplicationListener {

  ActionResolver actionResolver;

  SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
  Texture texture;
  Calculator calculator;

  public Surface(ActionResolver actionResolver) {
    this.actionResolver = actionResolver;
  }

  @Override
  public void create() {

    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ship.png"));
    calculator = new Calculator(texture);

      actionResolver.showToast("Tap screen to open Activity");

      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
            actionResolver.showToast("touchDown");
            actionResolver.showMyList();
            return true;
        }

        // overriding all other interface-methods the same way
      });
  }


@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    calculator.update();
    spriteBatch.begin();
    calculator.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();

}

// Overriding resize, pause, resume, dispose without functionality

}
```

**ActionResolver interface in libgdx main project**

```
public interface ActionResolver {
  public void showMyList();
  public void showToast(String toastMessage);
}
```

**Implementation of the ActionResolver interface within my Android project**

```
public class ActionResolverImpl implements ActionResolver {

Handler uiThread;
Context appContext;

public ActionResolverImpl(Context appContext) {
    uiThread = new Handler();
    this.appContext = appContext;
}

@Override
public void showMyList() {
    appContext.startActivity(new Intent(this.appContext, MyListActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void showToast(final String toastMessage) {
    uiThread.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(appContext, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

**Android Activity for inizializing the Suface-Class**

```
public class AndroidActivity extends AndroidApplication {

ActionResolverImpl actionResolver;

@Override
public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    actionResolver = new ActionResolverImpl(this);

    initialize(new Surface(actionResolver), false);
}
```

}

I also implemented the InputProcessor in my Surface-class, but this should not (and did not) make any difference. Any ideas, what I'm missing?

Comment: Which version of libgdx?

Comment: the newest one: 0.9.6 from http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/list

Comment: Is this the complete code? `InputProcessor` is an interface.

Comment: I edited my post. Now you see almost everything. I override all neccessary methods of both the InputProcessor interface and the ApplicationListener. But until now they are all completely empty execpt what you see above.

Comment: If they are empty its normal that the debugger doesn't stop in. Try to add simple Gdx.app.log("", "") calls in it.

Comment: As I said: They are all empty EXCEPT what you see above. I put a breakpoint on the line with the showToast call within the onTouchDown-Event, but the debugger doesnt stop there. Of course, I tried the same with all other event (put a line of code in them and set a breakpoint). No single event was fired.